# Safely and efficiently parse and replace tokens in a string

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a VBA function that will do some parsing / replacement according to tokens / placeholders.

Example:
Input: `"Username %u, date is %d."`
The function would replace %d with the current date and %u with the current username.

Sounds simple to implement, but here's a twist:
Regexps and Replace() are not safe. In the example above, if %u after replacement would contain another token (let's say `"Andy%d"`), there will be a recursive replacement and the output will mangled: `"Username Andy20170820, date is 20170820"`.

I could write this efficiently in C++ or some other *"proper"* language but I'm relegated to the VBA. I don't want to work on Chars inside a string as that doesn't look very efficient (and I might be using this formula to parse 10000 lines in an Excel sheet).

Searched and googled and even DuckDuckWent but to no avail.

Comment: Why would you need to apply the function recursively? Couldn't you just parse it once for the substitution tokens and then perform a replacement?

Comment: What I meant is that I perform replacement for one token and have (for my example): "Username Andy%d, date is %d". Then I perform the second replacement (for the next token) and have "Username Andy20170820, date is 20170820".

Comment: And, basically, this is what my question is about - how to do the search/replace without going down to the Char level? To use an inbuilt function or something...

Comment: Are the placeholders always of the form `%_` (where `_` is a single character)? If so, are all strings of the form `%_` placeholders?

Comment: Hi @John, I'm designing the placeholders so yes, I can make them follow the `%_` pattern. As for your second question - generally yes, but... I can't be sure of the data that will be pulled from somewhere after the replacements. I'd like to write a safe function that won't depend on any assumptions and could handle all the weird situations. _"Who's escaping the escape characters?"_ ;)

Comment: If you are going to use placeholders then you must make some assumptions, e.g. an actual username isn't `"Andy%d"`.

Comment: Seems like the only way is to go through source text searching for % with `InStr`, storing index in another variable and start each iteration where you ended in the previous one (plus length of name/date)

Comment: @JohnColeman, I would be loath to do so. The function is supposed be generic, robust and extendable; it will be used in various projects with unknown data formats. Even if I could assume the data returned would not contain magic symbols, that doesn't sound like safe programming to me! Think SQL injection / printf "format string attack" :)

Comment: @brainac, I had thought about something similar but it sounded too inefficient to me. Anyway, I have developed a solutoin and will post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, avoiding recursive replacement is quite easy - one would just loop through each char and replace on-the-fly, never coming back and avoiding the potential corruption. As I had originally written, what I had in my mind was a simple and elegant C++ parsing loop. Ported to VBA it would look horrible and be slow *(the more I code in VBA the more I miss C++/C#)*.

Hence, here's another solution that is very robust and looks rather efficient, even though not as terse as one would like.
Tested, works. Safe, extendable and logical.

---

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'' Replace magic symbols (placeholders) with dynamic data.
''
'' Arguments: a string full of magic.
''
'' Placeholders consist of one symbol prepended with a %:
''    %d - current date
''    %t - current time
''    %u - username (user ID)
''    %n - full user name (usually name and surname)
''    %% - literal % (placeholder escape)
''    Using an unsupported magic symbol will treat the % literally, as if it had been escaped.
''    A single placeholder terminating the string will also be treated literally.
''    Magic symbols are case-sensitive.
''
'' Returns:   A string with no magic but with lots of beauty.
''
'' Examples:
'' "Today is %d" becomes "Today is 2018-01-26"
'' "Beautiful time: %%%t%%" yields "Beautiful time: %16:10:51%"
'' "There are %zero% magic symbols %here%.", true to its message, outputs "There are %zero% magic symbols %here%."
'' "%%% looks lovely %%%" would show "%% looks lovely %%" - one % for the escaped "%%" and the second one for the unused "%"!
''
'' Alexander Ivashkin, 26 January 2018
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function AI_ParseMagicSymbols(ByVal TextToParse As String) As String

Dim sFinalResult As String
Dim aTokenizedString() As String
Dim sTempString As String
Dim sPlaceholder As String
Dim sCurrentString As String
Dim iIterator As Integer
Dim iTokenizedStringSize As Integer
Dim bThisStringHasPlaceholder As Boolean

' Default placeholder is "%"
Const cPlaceholderSymbol As String = "%"

aTokenizedString = Split(Expression:=TextToParse, Delimiter:=cPlaceholderSymbol)
iTokenizedStringSize = UBound(aTokenizedString())
bThisStringHasPlaceholder = False
sFinalResult = ""

For iIterator = 0 To iTokenizedStringSize
sCurrentString = aTokenizedString(iIterator)

If bThisStringHasPlaceholder Then
    If sCurrentString <> "" Then
    sPlaceholder = Left(sCurrentString, 1)
    sTempString = Right(sCurrentString, Len(sCurrentString) - 1)

    ' This is the place where the MAGIC happens
    Select Case sPlaceholder
        Case "d":
        sCurrentString = Date & sTempString
        Case "t":
        sCurrentString = Time & sTempString
        Case "u":
        sCurrentString = Environ$("Username") & sTempString
        Case "n":
        sCurrentString = Environ$("fullname") & sTempString
        Case Else:
        sCurrentString = cPlaceholderSymbol & sCurrentString
    End Select
    Else
    ' We had two placeholders in a row, meaning that somebody tried to escape!
    sCurrentString = cPlaceholderSymbol
    bThisStringHasPlaceholder = False
    End If
End If

sFinalResult = sFinalResult & sCurrentString

If sCurrentString = "" Or (iIterator + 1 <= iTokenizedStringSize And sCurrentString <> cPlaceholderSymbol) Then
    ' Each string in the array has been split at the placeholders. If we do have a next string, then it must contain a magic symbol.

    bThisStringHasPlaceholder = True
    ' Even though it is called "...ThisString...", it concerns the NEXT string.
    ' The logic is correct as we will check this variable on the next iteration, when the next string will become ThisString.
Else
    bThisStringHasPlaceholder = False
End If

Next iIterator

AI_ParseMagicSymbols = sFinalResult

End Function
```